# Spread operator not working with express.js

Tags: express, ecmascript-6

```
app.post('/addfriends', (req, res) => {
  let newFriend = req.body.name;
  friends.push(newFriend)
  res.redirect('/friends')
})
```

This is a code i'm working on. just wondering how can i use `{[...fiends], newFriend}` in place of .push() mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{[...fiends], newFriend}` is not going to achieve what you are trying to do.

Try this (assuming your friends array is mutable):

```
let friends = ['Joe', 'Chris'];

app.post('/addfriends', (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.body;
  friends = [...friends, name];
  res.redirect('/friends')
})
```

P.S. As a sidenote, I would suggest you to read through [RESTful API design guidelines](https://hackernoon.com/restful-api-designing-guidelines-the-best-practices-60e1d954e7c9) for how to construct your endpoints.

It's generally bad API design to use verbs in endpoint url names (like "add", "delete" etc...). That's what REST methods are for.

Comment: Glad to help:) Then you can mark the answer as correct, so it's clear for everyone ;)